# How to use `pexpect` on windows to read the "welcome message" like `telnetlib3`?

Tags: python, windows, telnet, pexpect

I want to use `pexpect` on Windows to open a telnet connection and to be able to read the "welcome message" (i.e. the output you get when you connect to some device). This is working with `telnetlib3` using the following code

```
import asyncio
import telnetlib3

async def foo():
    reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection("192.168.200.10", 9000)
    data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(4096), timeout=2)
    print(data)

asyncio.run(foo())
```

but this unfortunately uses asynchronous methods and hence is very cumbersome to use.

To avoid these issues I want to use `pexpect` to do the same, but with the following code I am not able to get that "welcome message" as for `telnetlib3`:

```
import time
from pexpect import popen_spawn

session = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("telnet 192.168.200.10 9000")
time.sleep(5)
data = session.read_nonblocking(4096, 1)
print(data)
```

In that case, I do not get any output. Is there something I am missing? How to get the "welcome message" using `pexpect` on Windows?

Running the command

```
telnet 192.168.200.10 9000
```

in a Windows terminal works as expected, i.e. I get this "welcome message".

The problem seems to be part of the "telnet" "negotiation" when the server sends commands like "IAC" and "DO", which I do not read on the client side (see [HERE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1091)). But why does this work for telnetlib3 but not for telnetlib? What is the difference?

Comment: Alex, have you tried using my reasoning?
[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76751002/21485801)

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
import time
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn

session = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("telnet telehack.com")
try:
    session.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=2)
except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
    pass

print(session.before.decode())
```

Running this against [telehack](https://telehack.com/) (on my linux system; I am assuming that Windows telnet will behave similarly) produces:

```
Trying 64.13.139.230...
Connected to telehack.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Connected to TELEHACK port 218

It is 5:36 am on Monday, July 17, 2023 in Mountain View, California, USA.
There are 125 local users. There are 26647 hosts on the network.
.
.
.
```

This code works by:

1. Waiting for a disconnect (`pyexpect.EOF`)
2. Using the `timeout` parameter on the `expect` method to time out if we don't receive it in 2 seconds
3. Looking at the `before` attribute (text received *before* the expected string) to get the information we want

Comment: Thanks for this solution, for me it also works on Linux. But not on windows. Here I do not get any output (having tried `ncat` and `telnet`). Running `telnet` directly in a powershell works as expected, i.e. I see the message.

Comment: Bummer. I don't have immediate access to a Windows system to test things out. I'll see about setting up a VM this evening.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to solve your question using [pexcept](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect), but it appears that it doesn't work properly on Windows (refer to [these open issues](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+wexpect)). They all recommend using the [wexpect](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect) alternative. I also tried wexpect, but it exhibits similar issues to pexpect. Finally, I came across [this issue](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues/40) which suggests that the actual problem lies with the Telnet Client in Windows.

By the way, I understand that you want to use pexcept, but I highly recommend considering a pure Python solution. Currently, there are three good alternatives available:

**Standard [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) library:**

First implementation: Utilize the `expect` method with a `timeout` and always expect `"unavailable data"` to prompt the client to wait until the timeout is reached. Alternatively, you can implement the timeout logic manually, but using the library to handle it is recommended:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet

with Telnet("telehack.com") as telnet:
    index, match, data = telnet.expect([b"unavailable data"], timeout=5)
    print(data.decode())
```

By executing it, the following result is obtained:

[image]

Second implementation: Utilize the `read_some`, `read_eager`, or preferably `read_very_eager` methods, iterating over them for a specific number of attempts, and introducing a sleep period for each attempt:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
from time import sleep

MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10
EACH_ATTEMPT_SLEEP = 0.2

with Telnet("telehack.com") as telnet:
    data = ""
    for i in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
        data += telnet.read_very_eager().decode()
        sleep(EACH_ATTEMPT_SLEEP)

    print(data)
```

By executing it, the following result is obtained:

[image]

Both implementations work perfectly. However, as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html), the module will be removed in Python 3.13:

> Deprecated since version 3.11, will be removed in version 3.13: The telnetlib module is deprecated (see PEP 594 for details and alternatives).

**The synchronous [Exscript](http://exscript.readthedocs.io/) library:**

It offers a highly similar interface to the standard telnetlib library and is endorsed by [PEP 0594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#deprecated-modules):

```
from time import sleep
from Exscript.protocols.telnetlib import Telnet

MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10
EACH_ATTEMPT_SLEEP = 0.5

telnet = Telnet(host="telehack.com")

data = ""
for i in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    data += telnet.read_very_eager()
    sleep(EACH_ATTEMPT_SLEEP)

telnet.close()

print(data)
```

I attempted this on Windows, but unfortunately, it resulted in a `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found error`, which appears to be a bug. Consequently, I made a modification to `Exscript\protocols\telnetlib.py, line 48`, changing to `self.msg('IAC DO %s', ord(opt) if opt else '')` with the intention of resolving the issue. After implementing this change, the error disappeared, and the code worked flawlessly:

[image]

**The asynchronous [telnetlib3](https://telnetlib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:**

This is also a renowned library that is endorsed by [PEP 0594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#deprecated-modules). However, it operates entirely in an asynchronous manner, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive response, but the two `telnet` suggestions do not seem to work. I do not get the welcome message. `excript` does not seem to be pip installable and does not seem to be maintained anymore. And `telnetlib3` works, but, as mentioned earlier as well, uses an asynchronous manner which I want to avoid by all means possible as this is not usable.

Comment: @Alex It's weird because I've tested all of my solutions and ideas on Windows 10 with Python 3.10.11, and it took me a few hours. I have also included result images for each solution. Since you mentioned the requirement for them to work on Windows, I didn't test them on Linux. Could you please let me know which versions of Windows and Python you are using so I can ensure compatibility in that environment as well?

Comment: Hello, I just repeated your suggestion with the `unavailable data` in it (I use this line literally as you have written, not sure if that is how I should use it), and it does not seem to work for Ubuntu VM (running on windows), nor directly on windows 10.

Comment: @Alex So, could you please tell me your Windows and Python versions?

Comment: windows 10, python 3.10.11

Comment: @Alex What did you get? An empty string or something? Could you please increase the `timeout`?

Comment: Output: see here: https://imgur.com/a/7B4sNAb. Increasing timeout to 15 seconds does not change the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254591/discussion-between-alireza-roshanzamir-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it is not working may be due to the `time.sleep(5)` line since connections can take varying amounts of time, therefore it might be executing too soon or too late. This might work:

```
import time
from pexpect import popen_spawn

session = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("telnet 192.168.200.10 9000")

try:
    session.expect('Connected.*Escape character is', timeout=5)
except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
    print("ERROR: failed to find expected pattern within timeout period")
    # do something such as retry the operation or exit the program

else:
    data = session.read_nonblocking(4096, 1)
    print(data)
```

Edit:

I'm not entirely sure, but apparently it is better to use:

```
session = pexpect.spawn("telnet 192.168.200.10 9000")
```

I don't have much experience with telnet or pexpect, so this is just what I can find online and through the documentation. Sorry if it doesn't change anything

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but when running the code I immediately receive a EOF error in the `session.expect` line.

Comment: @Alex there may be a delay from the telnet server, you could try adding a `time.sleep()` for a few seconds before the `data = session.read_nonblocking(4096, 1)` to check if that is the problem i think

Comment: Additionally you could add a `if session.isalive():` before it as well

Comment: Adding a `time.sleep` before `data = session.read_nonblocking(4096, 1)` does not make sense as I get the EOF before. Adding the sleep right after the `popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` command does not change the outcome. And `session` does not have `isalive()` as it is a `popen_spawn` object it seems ...